# MMO игровой сервер на Python

Tags: python, разработка-игр, сервер

Хотелось бы написать игровой сервер полностью на Питоне. Стоит ли писать на питоне? Какие минусы в будущем могут проявиться? Какую версию и фреймворк использовать?

Comment: @hunter33, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, какие варианты вы еще рассматриваете и т. д.

Comment: На питоне можно написать прототип (так собственно делают в Яндексе). Когда будет рабочий клиент и сервер, можно будет оценить качество протокола и мутные моменты. А потом начать переписывать клиент/сервер на чем то побыстрее - к примеру на плюсах. Так как сервер/клиент есть, то отлаживать будет на порядок быстрее.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Может быть, я окажусь не прав, но... Если хотим писать на Питоне, то не факт, что получится что-то крутое. Питон, эта некая бензопила, когда ты один в лесу, она тебе поможет, но если хочешь сделать что-то поистине крутое, бери или си с плюсами или сишарп.

Answer (score -2):

Если проект любительский и не предполагается зарабатывать деньги, иметь в онлайне 5000 игроков, и имя игры работает через **Dynamiс DNS** -- смело пишите на питоне.
Если же не выполняется 2 условия из 3 -- думайте сразу, что вы будете делать дальше, когда окажется, что мощности сервера не хватает.
Можно прикрутить **cython** по мере необходимости, но готовьтесь к тому, что могут быть странные глюки, например, с **cython** фактически не работает модуль **multiprocessing**.